# Concurrent updates with play ebean : avaje.ebean.Model.save()

Tags: playframework, ebean

Entity named Customer has ‘Name’, ‘Age’ as fields.

cust1 has values ‘Sammy’, ‘23’ in DB

How’s the following scenario handled?

1. Thread 1 & Thread 2 query cust1
2. Thread 1 modifies Name to ‘Manny’ and Age to ‘25’ and triggers cust1.save()
3. Thread 2 modifies only Age to ’27’ and triggers cust1.save()

What will be the resulting entry in the DB?

1. Manny, 27

   OR
2. Sammy, 27 (because Thread 2 had retrieved name as ‘Sammy’ and updated only age)

I guess the answer is 1, the reason being eBean always returns the same instance of an object if one is already present in the persistence context. If this is true, then how does eBean manage concurrent updates to the same object by multiple threads? What if in the above example, the two threads tried to change ‘age’ concurrently?

Comment: You have defined a (test) scenario, I would suggest: turn Ebean Sql logging on and find out what is happening.

Comment: Are you intentionally leaving out a @Version property?